# Recursive php menu

Tags: php

I have been searching around for some time but cannot seem to find an answer to my problem.

I have a deep nested array that I need to turn into a nested menu.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/98e0dcf4f2aef40a1da6

I would like it to end up as something like the following.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0dd4c7d047f11a5ce82

```php
class foo {

    function NavigationBuild($routes, $child = false) {
        if ($child) {
            foreach($routes as $route = > $row) {
                if (is_array($row['children'])) {
                    $output. = self::NavigationBuild($row['children'], true);
                } else {
                    $output. = "<li>".$val['route']."MEEEEE</li>";
                }

            }

        } else {
            $output. = '<ul>';
            foreach($routes as $route = > $row) {
                if (!strlen($row['parent'])) {
                    $output. = "<li>".$route."</li>";
                }
                foreach($row['children'] as $key = > $val) {
                    if (is_array($val['children'])) {
                        $output. = self::NavigationBuild($val['children'], true);
                    } else {
                        $output. = "<li>".$val['route']."MEEEEE</li>";
                    }
                }

            }
            $output. = '</ul>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any examples of what you've tried?

Comment: You might want to figure out the editor, or your question will be closed for not including code.

Comment: What is annoying about pasting in code, highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button in the toolbar?

Comment: Ok so anyone have any useful comments regarding my question asides attacking my posting method?

Comment: OK: what have you tried, where are you stuck and what is your question exactly?

Comment: Refreshed it with a code sample I have tried - in various ways.

Please excuse the lack of indenting, the editor didn't like tabs I can only assume

Comment: And whomever submitted a review of my question for saying "Happy new year"... Grow up dude, I was being polite

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - seems some sleep was needed.

Thanks to all USEFUL input